# How do you keep a port open automatically for testing in VS Code web applications?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to launch a server for an web application that uses the following packages: nodemon (automatically restarts server), express, ejs, node.js, lodash, morgan, and mongoose.

Every time I activate the server with the following code in the VS Code terminal **nodemon app.js** or **nodemon start** I get an error message informing me the port 3000 (one I use for testing) is already in use. I found a solution to solve this in the windows command prompt by entering **npx kill-port 3000** in terminal. But I find this repetitive and annoying doing this every single time I update my app.js server code. Is there a more perminent solution to remove the need to type in the windows command prompt terminal?

**Operating System:** Windows 10
**IDE:** Visual Studio Code: Version: 1.66.2 (user setup)
**Error info:**
node:events:498
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1330:16)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1378:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:1465:7)
at Function.listen (C:\Users\Gamer\Documents\Visual Studio Code repositories\M06 Tutorial Lessons 8-10\node-crash-course-lesson-8\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)
at C:\Users\Gamer\Documents\Visual Studio Code repositories\M06 Tutorial Lessons 8-10\node-crash-course-lesson-8\app.js:10:25Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
at emitErrorNT (node:net:1357:8)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: -4091,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 3000

Comment: There may be more going on here than meets the eye, but since you're running this on Windows, you can find what programs by following along with this article: https://veerasundar.com/blog/how-to-check-which-application-is-using-which-port/

Comment: Why not just use another port?

Comment: "*Every time I activate the server*" - why do you activate it multiple times in the first place? `nodemon` will automatically restart the server when you change `app.js` already. Just start it once and leave it running.

Comment: It is possible for the server to shut down automatically when the window in VS Code is closed down (At least for me).

Comment: But regardless I think I figured out the issue that was causing this.